# How do I define my own mymod function?

Tags: sml, smlnj

I am trying to define my own mymod function where mod is usual 3 mod 2 =1 function.
I dont know where to start. Any Suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't know where to start, here are a few hints:

1) `mymod` should be an infix function. The proper syntax for this is

```
infix mymod;
fun x mymod y = ...
```

2) You should find out how to implement `mymod` using `-`, `*` and `\`. I suggest you try out a few examples by hand before writing the function.

3) It's up to you to handle the *division by zero* case.